# python pygame key held down

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a plane keep moving left when hold left key down, I am using pygame.key.get_pressed(), but only response once just like normal pygame.KEYDOWN
only print 'move to right ' once

Can anyone help please?

```
def key_control(hero_temp):
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        print('Game Exit')
        exit()

        key_state = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key_state[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            print('move to right')
            hero_temp.x += 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            print('move to left')
            hero_temp.x -= 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_UP]:
            print('move to top')
            hero_temp.y -= 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            print('move to right')
            hero_temp.y += 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            print('space/shoot')
            hero_temp.fire()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only calling `key_state = pygame.key.get_pressed()` inside you loop where you iterate over every event. Simply take it out of there and it should work.

The problem is that it will only check for the pressed buttons if there was a new event. If there was no new event it won't check the pressed buttons and the code won't be executed

```
def key_control(hero_temp):
    key_state = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_state[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        print('move to right')
        hero_temp.x += 10
    if key_state[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        print('move to left')
        hero_temp.x -= 10
    if key_state[pygame.K_UP]:
        print('move to top')
        hero_temp.y -= 10
    if key_state[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        print('move to right')
        hero_temp.y += 10
    if key_state[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        print('space/shoot')
        hero_temp.fire()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Only gets run if there are new events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print('Game Exit')
            exit()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it didn't work, still print once every time I press and hold key down

Comment: hi，I posted the code below，please have a look, thanks

Comment: @H.Dai Ok, I probably didn't make that clear enough. You should also move all the checks for `key_state[pygame.K_]` outside of the for loop too. See my updated answer. Also, it would be better if update your question instead of submitting an answer with the updated code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def key_control(hero_temp):
    key_state = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print('Game Exit')
            exit()

        if key_state[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            print('move to right')
            hero_temp.x += 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            print('move to left')
            hero_temp.x -= 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_UP]:
            print('move to top')
            hero_temp.y -= 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            print('move to right')
            hero_temp.y += 10
        if key_state[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            print('space/shoot')
            hero_temp.fire()
```